# How to test significance of two ROC with MLeval

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, roc

I've two ROC derived from `caret` and I'd like to test if the relative curves are statistically different:

```
library(MLeval)

## Unique ML group of library's toy data
levels(as.factor(predsc$Group))

## Comparing two models
res <- evalm(list(fit1,fit2),gnames=c('ranger','gbm'), rlinethick=0.8, fsize=8, plots='r')
```

[image]

How I can verify if these ROCs are statistically different? In past I used `roc.test` but I don't figure out how to use it with this `MLeval` objects.

Comment: What do you want to know, if the curves themselves are different or if the AUCs are different?

Comment: @Dave a need curve comparison p-value. [roc.test](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/versions/1.16.2/topics/roc.test)

Answer (score 2):

Concordance probability (AUROC; c-index) are not appropriate for comparing two models, because of lack of statistical power.  See [fharrell.com/post/addvalue](http://fharrell.com/post/addvalue) for measures that are sensitive enough to be used for such comparisons.

Comment: This is the right answer and where I was going with my comment. However, I can imagine a scenario where a boss/reviewer/tyrant insists on using ROC curves and demands to know if the differences between two are statistically significant.

Comment: I know this happens but you have to stick to principles and avoid putting yourself in a situation where uninformed people rule the day.  Bosses can be replaced; there is a shortage of statisticians/data scientists so we have the luxury of not being stuck.  But there are rare occasions where doing a supplementary subservient suboptimal analysis that accompanies the appropriate analysis is helpful.

Comment: The scenario is referring to a reviewer. How I can solve this elegantly?

Comment: I would say that the test for differences in concordance probabilities (AUROCs) lacks statistical power because it does not reward extreme predictions that are right, being only a function of ranks of predicted values.  Tests should be based on proper accuracy scores, one of which is the log likelihood in a statistical model.  Differences in c-indexes are equivalent to differences in Wilcoxon statistics, which are never used.  I.e. it's comparing how A and B compare to how B and C compare using the Wilcoxon test.  Instead we need a head-to-head comparison A vs C.